# How to get W32 handle access?

Tags: windows, winapi

Say, I did

```
HANDLE h = CreateFileA ("foobar", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, 
    OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);
```

Now handle `h` has GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE access (if the call succeeded).

**Question**: What function should i call on `h` to get back its access mode (that is, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE)?

**Example**: `GetStdHandle (STD_INPUT_HANDLE)` returns *some* handle that *somehow* ended up being your stdin. You don't know if it's a file, or a pipe, or something else (there are ways to get handle type, but that's not the point here). And it might have any access (`CreateProcess` does not check handles you give it in `STARTUPINFO`). Is there a way to get its access mask (other than trying appropriate calls on it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`NtQueryObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432383.aspx) passing `ObjectBasicInformation`.

Comment: Works! Interesting fact: according to the value that NtQueryObject gives me, W32 (NT 6.1.7601) will always give you FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | SYNCHRONIZE whether you ask for it or not. At least, when you open a normal file.